# Why modulo prime prefered over modulo composite?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

In encryption process (aes encryption), and also in Galois field, a prime number is always used to perform the modulo operation. So I wanted to know the reason for using only prime numbers for modulo operations ?

Comment: The are not preferred in some general sense, it depends on your purposes at hand.  People work modulo $n$ for $n$ not prime all the time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but a nice property is that modulo a prime, every number (not equivalent to zero) has a multiplicative inverse. That is, if $m\not\equiv 0\text{ mod }p$ then there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $mn\equiv 1\text{ mod }p$ (for instance $n=m^{p-2}$ will work by Fermat's Little Theorem).

Comment: But if $n$ is prime there are a bunch of things that are true that aren't true otherwise.  For example there's a single number $m$ such that powers of $m$ give you all non-zero residues.  That's only true if the modulo is prime and can be a quite useful fact.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific about its purpose !
For encryption purposes(aes encryption), modulo prime is always preferred, so I wanted to know the mathematical reason for using prime numbers for modulo and not composite.

Comment: In general, modulo prime is not "preferred" over modulo composite, however the equivalence classes of integers modulo a prime form a field. These are known as finite fields, and modulo composite does not share this property.

Comment: [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) is applicable for prime numbers: $xy\equiv 0$ mod $p$ implies $x\equiv 0$ or $y\equiv 0$ mod $p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nice things about primes is that when looking at the numbers modulo a prime, you can always "divide" by anything non-zero.

In particular, if you want to solve the equation
$$
ax \equiv b \pmod p
$$
where $a \not \equiv 0$, and $b$ is any number, there exists some $(1/a)$, so that
$$
(1/a)ax \equiv (1/a)b
$$
or in other words,
$$
x \equiv b/a
$$
In mathematical terms, the numbers modulo a prime form a *field*, whereas the numbers modulo a composite number only form a *ring*.

To see how this *doesn't* work for composites, note that
$$
2x \equiv 1 \pmod 6
$$
has *no* solution, which is to say that $2$ has no multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Two facts come to my mind:

1. $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ has a ring structure. The set of non-zero elements of $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ is a (cyclic) group under multiplication if and only if $n$ is a prime number.
2. Let $n= p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_r^{a_r}$. Chinese Remainder Theorem tells you that $$x = y \mod{n}$$
   is equivalent to 
   $$x = y \mod{p_i^{a_i}} \ \ \ \ \mbox{for all } i$$
   so modular equations can be split into simpler ones.